# Javascript Switch Case Error with window.onload

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have a switch case with a window.onload function.

Here's the code:

```
window.onload = ButtonClicked();

function ButtonClicked() {
    document.getElementById("Easy").onclick = alertMessage();
    document.getElementById("Intermediate").onclick = alertMessage();
    document.getElementById("Advanced").onclick = alertMessage();
}
function alertMessage() {
    switch(this.id) {
        case "Easy":
            alert("Easy Content.")
        break;
        case "Intermediate":
            alert("Intermediate Content.")
        break;
        case "Advanced":
            alert("Advanced Content.")
        break;
    default:

    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work? I've been trying to fix this problem for awhile and I still don't know how to fix it. Is it the `window.onload` part that doesn't work? Or is it not calling the functions? Or is the `switch` case not working?

Comment: You're calling the method, not assigning it.

Comment: Try `window.onload = ButtonClicked;` instead of `window.onload = ButtonClicked()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are setting listeners to DOM elements you can't use parenthesis (except some cases). I mean 
`window.onload = ButtonClicked;` not `window.onload = ButtonClicked();` because `ButtonClicked` is the name of the function (a reference to it) while `ButtonClicked()` calls (i.e. executes) the function. The same reasoning could be done for the onclick listeners.

Here is the working code:

```
window.onload = ButtonClicked;
function ButtonClicked() {
    document.getElementById("Easy").onclick = alertMessage;
    document.getElementById("Intermediate").onclick = alertMessage;
    document.getElementById("Advanced").onclick = alertMessage;
}

function alertMessage() {
    switch (this.id) {
    case "Easy":
        alert("Easy Content.");
        console.log("Easy Content");
        break;
    case "Intermediate":
        alert("Intermediate Content.");
        console.log("Intermediate Content");
        break;
    case "Advanced":
        alert("Advanced Content.");
        console.log("Advaced Content");
        break;
    default:
    }
}
```